# FB.Event.subscribe to respond after the fb:like post wall dialogue closes

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this fb:like button...

And I am redirecting/responding when the like button has been liked. Using FB.Event.subscribe...

```
FB.init();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function(href) {
        var data = { action: "virallocker", myID: "'.$my_id.'"};
        jQuery.post("viral-lock.class.php", data, function(response) {
            if (virallocker_use) location.reload();                 
        }); 
    });
});
```

See what happens as standard when you click a 'Like Button' - the post wall dialogue appears...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVJSm.jpg

Now the problem I am having is that the location.reload(); in the javascript, is firing before the 'Post to wall' dialogue has been completed or closed.

`location.reload();` runs when the Like button is clicked.

My question is, can someone help me adjust the script so the response runs after the Post to wall dialogue has been closed or posted, instead of the 'Like' button being clicked.

See my problem here on the 'Like' button... http://goo.gl/9efLZ

Also posted here [www.javascriptquestions.com](http://www.javascriptquestions.com/question/showChronoLoggedIn/id/50)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook won't let you submit to the wall automatically when you click "Like" anymore. The user has to write something and post it for themselves. What I did is let the user wait 15 seconds and in the meanwhile aftre the clicked "Like" they have enough time to post a comment and a link to their wall.

So instead of location.reload(); place StartTheCounter(); and this should fix things.

```
// Start The counter
// At what number shall the countdown counter start?
CounterStart = 15;

// This function CustomAction() can be modified to do 
// whatever you want done every second.

function CustomAction() {
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 'You\'ll be automatically redirected </br> within ' + CounterStart + ' seconds.';
} // end of function CustomAction()

// end of JavaScript customization


function Decrement() {
    CounterStart--;
    CustomAction();
    if(CounterStart <= 0) { 

    //alert('Timer reached 0'); 
    window.location.href = "http://www.domain.com/new-location.php";

    }
    else { setTimeout('Decrement()',1000); }
}

function StartTheCounter() {
    setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
```